# Loading random form into jQuery Tools overlay

Tags: jquery

I asked how to load a random form in another thread and got great answers. Here is what I got and verified to work

```
$(function() {
 $("a.random")click.(function){
    $(".test_form").hide();
    var formNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);//will equal a number between 0 and 3
    $("#form" + formNumber).show();
 });
});
```

I need to apply this somehow to a jQuery Tools overlay that is being triggered as such

```
<a href="Forms/SupportFormTest.php" rel="#overlayForm">
```

and modify the href somehow to include the a reference to the function. would simply removing the href and using a class work? But then I would somehow have to add a path to the forms they are in another directory "/Forms". Help is much appreciated, the flowplayer.org forms are less than helpful

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *"modify the href somehow to include the a reference to the function"*? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Matt well the href points to a specific file, I want to load them randomly and I 'assumed' that pointing to a specific file would not allow that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to attach arbitrary data to an element.</s>

If it's just string data you're looking to store, you can instead use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to save the string to an attribute on the element. For HTML-5-compliant goodness, use an attribute that starts with `data-`.

---

*Edit* as requested, lazy copypasta:

I don't know PHP, and I definitely don't know how your site is set up, but the basic idea would be:

1. link to `Forms/RandomForm.php`
2. `RandomForm.php` would send an HTTP redirect to the browser, telling it to request an actual form page, **chosen at random** - say, `Forms/Form2.php`.
3. The browser now has the actual form to put into the overlay.

Does that sound reasonable? If you do still want to have the randomization in the browser, could you explain exactly what you're trying to randomize?

Comment: @Matt - appreciate the info, could you possibly show me a little more on how to do this with the code I provided? I am not familiar with .data and how to use it. Ill check out the documentation in the meantime. thx Matt!

Comment: @Dirty: I can certainly try, but I'm still not clear on exactly what you're trying to accomplish. I think your other comment just confused me further.

Comment: @Matt - I have 4 forms that serve the same purpose but are different in content and layout. Currently, I have several buttons on my site that when clicked load the current contact form in an jQuery Tools overlay. I want to add a function to the button so that when clicked, would load one of 4 forms randomly. Does that help? thx man

Comment: @Dirty: yes, getting there. Is each form at a different URL? Is that why you say you need to modify the `href`? Why don't you just do the randomization server-side? Are all 4 forms already loaded into the page when the overlay is shown?

Comment: @Matt - yes each form would have a different filename/URL. How would I do the randomization server-side? I am using PHP for the site. Right now, only the individual form that is requested in the href is loaded into the overlay.

Comment: @Dirty: I don't know PHP, and I definitely don't know how your site is set up, but the basic idea would be: 1. link to `Forms/RandomForm.php` 2. `RandomForm.php` would send an HTTP redirect to the browser, telling it to request an actual form page, **chosen at random** - say, `Forms/Form2.php`. 3. The browser now has the actual form to put into the overlay. Does that sound reasonable? If you do still want to have the randomization in the browser, could you explain exactly _what_ you're trying to randomize?

Comment: The theory is what I needed. I can find example somewhere and beat it into submission. I had not thought of using a controller file to do it. I thought JS click function was the way to go. I will go with what you suggested, prob. solved